# Scrolling in nested TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have a wpf application where I use a tabcontrol. The structure looks like this:

```
/*MainView*/
<UserControl>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type tapViewModels:TabViewModel}">
            <tabViews:TabView />
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <ScrollViewer Name="MainScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                ...
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                <dx:DXTabControl ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemHeaderTemplate>
                    <dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=Content}" />     /*Content = new TabViewModel()*/
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </dx:DXTabControl.ItemTemplate>
                </dx:DXTabControl>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>

/*TabView*/
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            ...
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <dxg:GridControl>
                <dxg:TableView>
                   ...
                </dxg:TableView>
            </dxg:GridControl>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

When I scroll up while hovering the GridControl I want the scroll event to "bubble" up if the GridControl is allready scrolled to the top. And of course the same when scrolling down while beeing at the bottom.

My problem is, that the GridControl and the ScrollViewer exist in two different views and with two different ViewModels. So how can I make this work?

I would pref. a MVVM solution, but at this point I'm open for anything!

Comment: If I understand you correctly. You want to scroll to the top of the GridControl, and once it's scrolled to the top, then the scroll of the other view will start kicking in. Perhaps you could try putting both of the views inside one scrollviewer? Just an idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the MouseWheel event on the lower control and check if it is scrolled to the top and then raise the event of the upper control:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <wpfApplication3:ControlA x:Name="A" Grid.Row="0" />
    <wpfApplication3:ControlB x:Name="B" Grid.Row="1" PreviewMouseWheel="HandleMouseWheel"/>
</Grid>
```

Then in the HandleMouseWheel event:

```
private void HandleMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        var controlB = sender as ControlB;

        if (controlB != null && e.Delta > 0 && controlB.Scroll.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            var eventArg = new MouseWheelEventArgs(e.MouseDevice, e.Timestamp, e.Delta)
                {
                    RoutedEvent = UIElement.MouseWheelEvent,
                    Source = sender
                };

            A.Scroll.RaiseEvent(eventArg);
        }
    }
```

e.Delta checks you are mouse wheeling up and the VerticalOffset check ensures the control is already scrolled to the top.

This makes the assumption your usercontrols have a publically available scrollviewer in them, for example:

```
<UserControl>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="Scroll">
        <Grid Height="1000"></Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The two scrolls exists in different views. They are not lower/upper, but exist in a parent/child structure. "ScrollA" would not be accessible from where the event of "ScrollB" is fired.

Comment: The above shows how to handle the triggers for the scroll event needing to be re-raised; and then how to re-raise it on a different control.  So all you need to handle is how one object sends a message to another.  You have a few options.  1) have a reference to one ViewA inside ViewB and have ViewA call a public method on ViewB.  2) Allow ViewA to lookup ViewB from a global static reference.  3) If you are using PRISM use the EventAggregator to send a message between two otherwise decoupled components: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173.aspx.

Comment: I've updated the code to show an example which uses two different user controls